# Using Jest+Enzyme+React does not point the right line on error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

When I have an error in my test (let's say I use a function that does not exists with Jest), Jest does not point the right line for error. So If I use a function that does not exists:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Link)).to.have(...)
```

It displays:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

> 1 | import React from 'react';
    |                                                                   ^
  2 | import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
  3 | import Logo from '../header/logo.js';
  4 | import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/scenes/header/logo-test.js:1:596)
```

So  can dig in my files to find the right line, but I hope that Jest can point the right line? I'm not sure why this debug problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the complete error. I agree the error starts with

```
Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

But error log ends like following, where you can clearly see in which line the problem is. Correct me if you expect something else.

```
  10 |     const wrapper = shallow(<Field />);
  11 |     console.log(wrapper.debug());
  12 |     expect(wrapper.contains(<p id="hello" />)).toBeTruthy();
> 13 |     expect(wrapper.find("p").prop("id")).to.have("hello");
  14 |   });
  15 | });
```

For same I have created a sandbox where such error is coming and I can clearly see above mentioned behavior https://codesandbox.io/s/7z43vjlx

Comment: Thank you! The error I pasted is the whole error. There is no reference to another line and that's my problem: I don't know why Jest point the wrong line...  (but I know how to find the line by myself)

Comment: Did you take a look at the sandbox it is showing error line as well. Also can you remove the logo import from your test case. I think it not getting resolved properly.

Comment: Yes, thanks again! My problem must be due to something else I don't understand. Because in my project, I have this error. But not in sandbox, I agree.